# Put title on 2 lines when screen gets too small

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am currently building a **react** web application using **redux**. I'm trying to make the page as responsive as possible. At the moment, I have a title at the top that shows:

***Actions to do: Past due:***

When I lower the size of my page, the title replaces itself depending on the size of the screen as shown below.

1- `Actions to do: Past due:`

2- `Actions to do: Past
   due:`

3- `Actions to do:
   Past due:`

I would like to skip the second part and go automatically to 2 separated lines.

my code:

```
return (
    <h3><Translate value='application.my_actions_to_do'/> {totalCountDetection} <p className='ActionPastDue'> {exceedLimit > 0 && <Translate value='application.including' />} {exceedLimit} {exceedLimit > 0 && <Translate value='application.past_due' />} </p></h3>
  );
```

In this example, *Translate*, *totalCountDetection*, *exceedLimit* are all variables.

The 2 lines to be separated would be the 2 **Translate value=...** but only if my screen is small enough for them not to be able to fit on the same line.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to work on your mcve a bit. Your problem really has nothing to do with javascript or react but more with HTML and CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: My bad there, changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would using a `&nbsp;` solve this? For instance...

```
Actions to do: Past&nbsp;due:
```

This will make sure the words "Past" and "due" are always together.

Comment: Upvote, but I tend to do that in both blocks ... `Actions&nbsp;to&nbsp;do: Past&nbsp;due:` or `Actions to&nbsp;do: Past&nbsp;due:` leaving a normal space only in places where I want it to break.

Comment: Wow really like this answer a lot. In my situation, because I handle multiple languages, I need to return a string. How could I place the `&nbsp;` value in the string?
example: Translate variable is `past due`. Need it to be `past&nbsp;due` but **js** doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Marked this as the correct answer as it can be used in pretty much everything. For react users, see my answer for a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Group the phrases into span tags and tell the 2nd tag not to wrap. Run code snippet to see it in action.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  
  Default Behavior:
  <div style="width:200px;border:1px solid #000">
    <span>Actions to do: </span>
    <span>Past due:</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  Behavior I do not want:
  <div style="width:150px;border:1px solid #000">
    <span>Actions to do: </span>
    <span>Past due:</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  Behavior I want instead:
  <div style="width:150px;border:1px solid #000">
    <span>Actions to do: </span>
    <span style="white-space:nowrap;">Past due:</span>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution should work, but isn't there any other possible solution that has less code? Could I juste wrap `Actions to do:` and `Past due` in 2 span tags and force that when **due:** is put another line, to put the entire span on the other line?

Comment: Isn't that what the white-space;nowrap does? Or am I not understanding? My example is only an example. No one can copy and paste your code and run it, but they can with this answer.

Comment: If you were to do this rather than just use `&nbsp;` as Axion suggests, you could do `<span class="keep-together">Actions to do:</span> <span class="keep-together">Past due:</span>` and then style in CSS `.keep-together { white-space:nowrap; }`. Scattering `style="..."` throughout your markup totally defeats the purpose of style-sheets; it bloats your page, and you have to change it hundreds of places if you re-style things. I would fire you from my team if you did that.

Comment: @StephenP inline styles can work a bit differently within the context of react.

Comment: If the inline styles are part of a template that gets stamped out repeatedly, well that's ok, but I still prefer using classes to describe things.

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler way if you're using React like me, just wrap your text with `style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}`.

In my previous code, it would look like this:

```
return (
     <h3><Translate value='application.my_actions_to_do'/> {totalCountDetection} <p className='ActionPastDue' style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}> {exceedLimit > 0 && <Translate value='application.including' />} {exceedLimit} {exceedLimit > 0 && <Translate value='application.past_due' />} </p></h3>
);
```

Found this in Adrian Macneil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432576/reactjs-render-string-with-non-breaking-spaces).

If you're not using React, I recommend Axion's answer.
It works in React also, I find it just simpler to read by putting it in **style**.

Comment: Brilliant ! really helped