# Non breaking space for React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need to separate some data so that there is a space after a unit name. What is the proper way to add a space after your data call?

Since I am new to react I tried adding your basic `&nbsp;` with no results.

Example:

```
<span>{unit.name}&nbsp;</span>
```

I have also tried something like:

```
{unit.name, "\u00A0"}
```

and

```
<span>{unit.name}{' '}</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432576/reactjs-render-string-with-non-breaking-spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<span>{unit.name} </span>
```

You can just write a literal space.

Comment: Here is the sandbox to back up @Joss Classey's answer https://codesandbox.io/s/j7yn54wm05

Answer (score 1):

If it is a long text, you can go with something like this:

```
<span style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>Long line with no breaks</span>
```